# Relation between harmonic vector fields and harmonic maps

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $f:M\longrightarrow N$be a smooth map between Riemannian manifolds and $X\in \chi (M) $ be a harmonic vector field.

> What are some necessary and sufficient conditions for guaranting that $f_{\ast}X$ is a harmonic vector field?

Comment: Rarely is $f_*X = Tf\circ X\circ f^{-1}$ a well defined vector field.

Comment: Look for the literature on "harmonic morphisms" (and the right setup is pull-back of forms, not push-forward of vector fields).